# How can I use a 3rd party font on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, email, font, signature

**My Requirement**:
I am trying to use Orkney light font in HTML email signature in a iPad

**What I have got**:
Have configured email sign, no issues except the font used in my design is missing.

**What I want:**
How to install this Orkney light font in iPad

Comment: Even if you got it working on your own iPad, no-one else would be able to see it unless they installed it on their devices too. Their devices would just default to whatever the default font is.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by following these steps:
- send to your iPhone the signature text styled the way you want it (including font)
- copy the signature
- paste it as is in your signature settings

Voilà!

FYI, the steps are illustrated [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/07/11/html-signature-ios/) (despite the older iOS version)

Comment: How does this load a new font?